# Why would crontab PHP script execution differ from CLI?

Tags: php, cron

I have a PHP script that begins as follows:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

//set up google api client

$client = new \Google_Client();
```

When I execute directly from the command line using:

```
php /Users/xxxx/app.php
```

It executes normally. However when I include in crontab in the form:

```
30 7 * * * php /Users/xxxx/app.php
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_Client' not found in 
  /Users/xxxx/app.php:8
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /Users/xxxx/app.php on line 8
```

I haven't used cron much previously - any idea how I might rectify this?

Comment: That's weird, it passes the `require_once`, are you perhaps using `include_once` instead? It should stop there already as the relative path will not exist. You could try something like `cd /Users/xxxx && php app.php`

Comment: That did it! Thank you - I didn't know about '&&'.

Comment: Are these scripts run by the same user?

Comment: I suggest you don't write scripts than depend on working directory to load fixed assets. Why not `require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`? That's what they use in the [Basic usage](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) chapter of Composer documentation.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the first thing to do is to use the complete path to the php executable and maybe also try setting the cronjob to run as the same user from when you execute from cli:

From cli run

> which php

and insert the path in your cronjob (usually /usr/bin/php):

> 30 7 * * * YOUR_USER /PATH_TO_EXEC/php /Users/xxxx/app.php